# Derby database throws IndexOutOfBoundsException when updating a table row containing a SMALLINT field with 'NOT NULL DEFAULT 0' clause

Tags: java, sql, database, exception, derby

The very last version of Derby database throws IndexOutOfBoundsException when updating a table that has a row containing a SMALLINT type field with 'NOT NULL DEFAULT 0'.

**@Update:**

I have found the solution. Only if Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS is set by creating a PreparedStatement and there is a "SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0" type field in the table, IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

```
PreparedStatement p = connection.prepareStatement([update query...], Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
...
p.executeUpdate(); -> IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: Maybe...Are any of the current values null?  If so ensure they aren't by setting them to 0.  then apply your logic.  DEFAULT 0 only applies to new records; not existing.

Comment: @xQbert, thanks for the good tip. I have checked: the field is set to 1 in all the rows of the table. So something else is wrong.

Comment: Even if you can't reproduce the problem, make sure that you capture *all* the information from your production system. Follow this approach: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain Then update your question and include the *complete* exception chain in the question.

Comment: I have found that the exception occurs only if Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS is set and there is a "NOT NULL DEFAULT 0" clause on a table field. Maybe it is a bug in Derby? I will investigate it and add much more details.